# Leading order Taylor Series Represention of the following function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I am given with this function $$f=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+af_1(x)+bf_2(x)}},$$ where $$f_1=(1+x^2)^\nu,$$ and $$f_2=x^2(1+x^2)^{\nu-1},$$ where $\nu$ is a rational constant. I would want my $f$ to be of the following form: $$f\approx f(0)+c_1(f_1(x)-1)+c_2f_2(x).$$ In this scenario, what would be my $c_1$ and $c_2$ in terms of $a, b$ and $\nu$ which are all real constants?

Answer (score 1):

If we had $f(x) \approx f(0)+c_1f_1(x)+c_2f_2(x)$ then $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = f(0) = f(0) + c_1f_1(0) = f(0) + c_1.$ That doesn't look right.

What you can do is write

$$f(x) = (1+af_1+bf_2)^{-1/2} = (1+a)^{-1/2}[1+(a(f_1-1)+bf_2 )/(1+a)]^{-1/2}.$$

Then use $(1+h)^{-1/2} = 1 -h/2 + O(h^2)$ as $h\to 0,$ thinking of $h= (a(f_1-1)+bf_2 )/(1+a).$

Comment: I don't think that's right. If I use $$f(f_1,f_2)\approx f(0)+f_{f_1}(f_1-1)+f_{f_2} f_2,$$ I get a different result. More $f_{f_1}$ is the derivative of $f$ with respect to $f_1$ at $x=0$.

Comment: You should at least acknowledge that you changed the problem after I pointed out the error.